# Setting git proxy's without security compromise

Tags: git, proxy

I want to set my proxy to use with git. I know that I can use

```
git config --global http.https://domain.com.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port

git config --global http.https://domain.com.sslVerify false
```

My problem is that I don't want to expose the password of my user in the proxy server. This is a security problem as someone can search through my history and see the command (this a common machine). Is there a way to execute this command without exposing my password? I was thinking also to clean my bash history with something like

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c
```

but is this enough to protect my password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` you can set `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace` and prepend your `git`
commit with a whitespace.  From `man bash`:

```
HISTCONTROL
              A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the
              history list.  If the list of values  includes  ignorespace,  lines  which
              begin  with  a space character are not saved in the
              history list.
```

You might already have `HISTCONTROL` set to a sane value, check it:

```
$ echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoreboth
```

`ignoreboth` is a shortcut for `ignorespace` and `ignoredups`.

BTW, are you sure that nobody can read your `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: As it turns out gitconfig can be read by anyone. Can I chmod gitconfig to 700 and then edit it manually to add the wanted options?